# ServiceStack BSD version 3.9.71 and protobuf-net version

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I downloaded the ServiceStack BSD version  3.9.71 from Nuget

using the  commmands

Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71

and  Install-Package ServiceStack.Plugins.ProtoBuf -Version 3.9.71

I installed also the protobuf-net

Install-Package protobuf-net

but I have problem because the  ServiceStack 3.9.71  try to find the protobuf-net ver.2.0.0.640,

when the  last   version of protobuf  from Nuget is 2.0.0.668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NuGet packages doesn't specify a version constraint on them so they get the latest dependency, in this case **v2.0.0.668**. You could uninstall the current version of protobuf-net and just install the one that's needed, e.g:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package protobuf-net -Force

PM> Install-Package protobuf-net -Version 2.0.0.640
```

Otherwise another option is to add [Binding Redirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your web.config.

I'll look at specifying explicit versions for external NuGet dependencies in future.

Comment: VS2013.1 (I honestly don't know about VS2013.0, as I couldn't use it in anger due to a missing feature) has really good support for adding and maintaining binding redirects for you... which is nice.